# Cloud Run Inter Zone Egress

Tags: google-cloud-run

I have a question on inter-zone egress charges on Google Cloud Run (managed). As I understand there is no control over which zones Cloud Run chooses. So potentially when deploying several microservices talking to each other, there could be significant charges.

In kubernetes this can be alleviated via service topology (preferring same zone or even same host if available). Is there anyway to achieve this with Cloud Run?

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service-topology/

Comment: How did you calculate significant charges? There is no data in your question. Cloud Run is a managed service. That means you do not have that level of control in regards to container placement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Cloud Run pricing](https://cloud.google.com/run/pricing#pricing_table) and [internet egress pricing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/network-pricing#internet_egress) cost stays the same 
independent if apps are within the same zone or not.

Now if you plan to have heavy traffic between your apps you should consider using different setup. Either GKE or Cloud Run for Anthos will allow you to setup communication between your apps through internal IP addresses which is free of charge assuming they are in the same zone. Refer to this [table](https://cloud.google.com/compute/network-pricing#general).

Comment: ah, thanks for pointing that out, forgot they were non-private IP addresses. I would love to use Cloud Run for Anthos, but GCP have for now put that out of the reach of ordinary developers and reserved it for $CORP ($120k + annual contract).

Comment: May be you can set up some asynchronous communication through pub/sub topics and it will be cheaper option for you. You can try to compare possible costs with from GCP pricing calculator https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/.